# how to properly wait for another execution to finish if needed using LockService

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got an `on form submit` trigger for a Form/Sheet. I want to prevent two executions of code stepping on top of each other. I know I have to use [`LockService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) but I'm not entirely sure how. And I don't really know how to properly test my code/theory...

In the example at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock, it just waits 30 seconds for a lock. This seems risky because what happens if the other execution takes longer than 30 seconds? Instead, I think it would make more sense to wait indefinitely for the other execution to finish.

My thoughts so far:

```
// get a script lock
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();

// try to get a lock in 10 second intervals
// the probability that the form would be submitted twice
// at exactly the same time is very low
// so i'm not worried about waiting indefinitely in 10 second intervals
// if it can never get a lock the script will reach the script runtime quota and fail
// which will send me an email letting me know I need to manually rerun something
while (!lock.tryLock(10000)) { }

// do what i need to here

// release the lock
lock.releaseLock();
```

Comment: Batches of 10 seconds or a total of 30 minutes doesn't make a difference. If you chose to wait for 30 minutes and you get a lock in 10 seconds, you'll get a lock. The input argument is the **maximum** milliseconds to wait before throwing a error.

Comment: Oh. Well, now I feel dumb. So I really just need `var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); lock.waitLock(30 * 60 * 1000);`?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Comment: Want to put your comment as an answer so I can mark it so or should I just delete my very dumb question?

Comment: Added a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batches of 10 seconds or a total of 30 minutes wouldn't make a difference. If you chose to wait for 30 minutes and you are about to get a lock in 10 seconds, you'll get a lock in 10 seconds. The input argument is the **maximum** number of milliseconds to wait before throwing a error/returning and not the minimum.